# PhysicalAddress.Parse() won't parse lower cased string, is this a bug?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

*Note: Using .Net 4.0*

Consider the following piece of code.

```
String ad = "FE23658978541236";
String ad2 = "00FABE002563447E".ToLower();
try
{
    PhysicalAddress.Parse(ad);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //We dont get here, all went well
}
try
{
    PhysicalAddress.Parse(ad2);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //we arrive here for what reason?
}
try
{
    //Ok, I do it myself then.
    ulong dad2 = ulong.Parse(ad2, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    byte[] bad2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(dad2);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        bad2 = bad2.Reverse().ToArray<byte>();
    }
    PhysicalAddress pa = new PhysicalAddress(bad2);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //We don't get here as all went well
}
```

So an exception is thrown in PhysicalAddress.Parse method when trying to parse an address with lower case. When I look at the source code of .Net its totally clear to me why.
Its because of the following piece of code.

```
    if (value >= 0x30 && value <=0x39){ 
        value -= 0x30;
    } 
    else if (value >= 0x41 && value <= 0x46) {
        value -= 0x37;
    }
```

That is found within the `Parse` method.

```
    public static PhysicalAddress Parse(string address) {
    int validCount = 0; 
    bool hasDashes = false; 
    byte[] buffer = null;

    if(address == null)
    {
        return PhysicalAddress.None;
    } 

    //has dashes? 
    if (address.IndexOf('-') >= 0 ){ 
        hasDashes = true;
        buffer = new byte[(address.Length+1)/3];    
    }
    else{

        if(address.Length % 2 > 0){  //should be even 
            throw new FormatException(SR.GetString(SR.net_bad_mac_address));
        } 

        buffer = new byte[address.Length/2];
    } 

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++ ) {

        int value = (int)address[i];

        if (value >= 0x30 && value <=0x39){ 
            value -= 0x30;
        } 
        else if (value >= 0x41 && value <= 0x46) {
            value -= 0x37;
        }
        else if (value == (int)'-'){ 
            if (validCount == 2) {
                validCount = 0; 
                continue; 
            }
            else{ 
                throw new FormatException(SR.GetString(SR.net_bad_mac_address));
            }
        }
        else{ 
            throw new FormatException(SR.GetString(SR.net_bad_mac_address));
        } 

        //we had too many characters after the last dash
        if(hasDashes && validCount >= 2){ 
            throw new FormatException(SR.GetString(SR.net_bad_mac_address));
        }

        if (validCount%2 == 0) { 
            buffer[j] = (byte) (value << 4);
        } 
        else{ 
            buffer[j++] |= (byte) value;
        } 

        validCount++;
    }

    //we too few characters after the last dash
    if(validCount < 2){ 
        throw new FormatException(SR.GetString(SR.net_bad_mac_address)); 
    }

    return new PhysicalAddress(buffer);
}
```

Can this be considered a bug? Or is it so very wrong to use a lower cased hex values in a string? Or is there some convention I am unaware of.
Personally, I consider this programmer unfriendly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ok, it is stated in the manual. Looks to me as "He employee, this Parse method doesn't work with lower case!?", "Oh uh yeah boss, indeed, uhm... I'll add it to the documentation, so it's not a bug, hehe, alright?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The address parameter must contain a string that can only consist of
>   numbers and **upper-case letters** as hexadecimal digits. Some examples of
>   string formats that are acceptable are as follows .... Note that an address that contains f0-e1-d2-c3-b4-a5 will fail to parse and throw an exception.

So you could simply do: `PhysicalAddress.Parse(ad.ToUpper());`

Comment: RTFM applies here I guess. Didn't think of reading about the parse method of `PhysicalAddress`. I guess I couldn't imagine someone would want to restrict it to upper case only.

Comment: Always read the documentation first. Implementation might change if a feature is undocumented. If you think that this is a bug you should vote up [existing reports](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/331366/physicaladdress-parse-support-lower-case-hexadecimal-digits-or-explain-in-exception-message) or write a new one.

Comment: I am not to only one `bugged` with the `capitalized- only-restriction` apparently. Definitely going to vote for that one!

Comment: Accepted as answer because of the additional link provided: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/331366/physicaladdress-parse-support-lower-case-hexadecimal-digits-or-explain-in-exception-message otherwise I had to choose for the "No, it's only a bug..." answer of paxdiablo has he more strictly answers the question that it's not a bug.

Comment: That's okay, @Mike, it's not like I'm short on rep :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, it's only a bug if it doesn't do something the documentation states that it does, or it does something the documentation states that it doesn't. The mere fact that it doesn't behave as you expect doesn't make it a bug. You could of course consider it a bad design decision (or, as you put it so eloquently, programmer-unfriendly) but that's not the same thing.

I tend to agree with you there since I like to follow the "be liberal in what you expect, consistent in what you deliver" philosophy and the code could probably be easily fixed with something like:

```
if (value >= 0x30 && value <=0x39) { 
    value -= 0x30;
}
else if (value >= 0x41 && value <= 0x46) {
    value -= 0x37;
}
else if (value >= 0x61 && value <= 0x66) {  // added
    value -= 0x57;                          // added
}                                           // added
else if ...
```

though, of course, you'd have to change the doco as well, and run vast numbers of tests to ensure you hadn't stuffed things up.

Regarding the doco, it can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.parse.aspx) and the important bit is repeated below (with my bold):

> The address parameter must contain a string that can only consist of numbers and **upper-case letters** as hexadecimal digits. Some examples of string formats that are acceptable are as follows:

```
001122334455
00-11-22-33-44-55
F0-E1-D2-C3-B4-A5
```

> Note that an address that contains `f0-e1-d2-c3-b4-a5` **will fail to parse** and throw an exception.

Comment: I would have voted you up twice if possible, especially because of the usage of the word "eloquently". I had to look that one up!